# Problemas ao consultar api com axios

Tags: javascript, react, axios

Estou com problemas para consultar uma api com o axios, quando eu dou um GET o axios me retorna uma objeto normal, porém quando vou renderizar o conteúdo diz que a variável não contém nada.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import api from "./services/api";

function createParagraphs(data) {
  const paragraphs = data.map((info, index) => {
     return (
       <p>
         {info.cell}, {info.gender}
       </p>
    );
  });

  return paragraphs;
}

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    api
      .get("")
      .then((response) => setUser(response.data))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("ops! ocorreu um erro" + err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {createParagraphs(user['results'])}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que a ordem dos eventos que influencia no comportamento.
Quando a createParagraphs é chamada na reenderização os dados ainda não estão prontos.

Uma sugestão para você:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import api from "./services/api";

function createParagraphs(data) {
  const paragraphs = data.map((info, index) => {
     return (
       <p>
         {info.cell}, {info.gender}
       </p>
    );
  });

  return paragraphs;
}

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    api
      .get("")
      .then((response) => {
        setUser(response.data);
        const cont = createParagraphs(response.data['results']); 
        setContent(cont);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.error("ops! ocorreu um erro" + err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {content}
    </div>
  );
}
```